# Chip identification labeled as ER=4B

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

I'm looking for a datasheet of this chip `ER=4B`. It seems that it's some DC regulator. It is placed on a logic board of an LCD panel HM236WU1-100. It is powered by 5V. The second line imprinted on the chip `E1J` or `N18` is probably manufacture date.

Thank you

[image: LCD logic board]

Comment: Too many pins for a DC regulator I'd say... More like some custom IC/ASIC

Comment: Might be a specialised backlight driver?

Comment: Can this be a regulator with many outputs with different voltages? I think it produces different voltages for an LCD like VGH (+27V) for example.